# What was Adam's private name?

Tags: names, parashat-bereishit, adam

Interestingly, in English and other languages, we treat "Adam" as the private name, not as a noun, but in the Torah it is a noun, for example ([Ber 2.25](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.2.25?lang=bi&with=Onkelos%20Genesis&lang2=he)):

> וַיִּהְיוּ שְׁנֵיהֶם עֲרוּמִּים **הָאָדָם** וְאִשְׁתּוֹ וְלֹא יִתְבֹּשָׁשׁוּ׃

The two of them were naked, **the man** and his wife, yet they felt no shame.

So, did Adam have a private name at all?

Interestingly we saw the same difference in calling his wife's names: in the beginning, she was called "wife" as the Posuk says "ייקרא אישה" but later he calls he the name Chavah - "וַיִּקְרָא הָאָדָם שֵׁם אִשְׁתּוֹ חַוָּה" - specifically "שם". But Adam wasn't given a name.

Comment: Chazal refer to him as Adam HaRishon, which still just means “the first man.” I’d speculate based on that that he indeed did not have a personal name.

Comment: Actually, she was originally called Adam also - Bereishis 5:2 זכר ונקבה בראם ויברך אתם ויקרא את שמם אדם ביום הבראם